# weka apriori method

Tags: data-mining, weka

In weka, my main aim is to find all possible frequent item sets under the 0.004 support threshold. But, in weka, I have not seen any column for writing support threshold. It takes some arguments like -n -t -c -d . To run appriori with support threshold, what parameter should be written or how ca I run weka apriori with support threshold ?

Note : This is my first question there may be wrong part, please say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will give you all the command line parameters:

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.associations.Apriori -h
```

What you are looking for:

```
-M <lower bound for minimum support>
The lower bound for the minimum support. (default = 0.1)
```

Comment: should I decrease delta so that the 0.004 can be achieved from upper bound ?

Answer (score 1):

Weka’s Apriori mines association rules with min. support equal to the upper bound for minimum support and the 
given minimum confidence. If it obtains at least the required number of rules, it outputs this rules and stops. If it obtains less than the required number of rules, it decreases the min. support by delta. It repeats this process until it obtains enough rules or the min. support reaches the given lower bound for minimum support. 
(source: http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs4445/b12/Exams/solutions_cs4445_b12_exam2.pdf)